# Add class to parent element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, calendar

I have a Calendar this is the setup to mark the current day

```
if (i == day)  //if is current day
{
  $(this.parentNode).addClass('current');  // problem, doesn't work
  $("tr:last").append(td tag with class current);  // works fine
}
```

Comment: The obvious question is "what is `this`?"

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, a slightly better solution:

```
$(this).closest("td").addClass("current");
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents("tr").addClass("current");
```

http://api.jquery.com/parents/